# Converting numeric values in varchar to decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, type-conversion, varchar

Error converting numeric values from varchar datatype to decimal

```
select 
    case PCI1__c 
       when ISNUMERIC(rtrim(ltrim(PCI1__c))) 
          then convert(decimal(10, 2), PCI1__c)
          else null 
    end as PCI1__c 
from 
    MX_CREDIT_ANALYSIS;
```

Fyi, the column contains values like 'no revenue', 'two', 'revenue22', '5.5'

Getting error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '5.5' to data type int.

Comment: Please mention your SQL server version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the `CASE`, then

**Query**

```
select 
    case when ISNUMERIC(rtrim(ltrim([PCI1__c]))) = 1
    then convert(decimal(10, 2), PCI1__c)
    else null end as PCI1__c 
from [MX_CREDIT_ANALYSIS];
```

Answer (score 1):

[`isnumeric()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) returns an `integer`, so when you do a `CASE pci1__c WHEN isnumeric(...) ...` then `pci1__c`, which is a `varchar`, gets compared to an `integer`. In order to be able to do that comparison, the DBMS wants to upcast the `varchar` to an `integer`. That fails as (expected) `integer` representations don't include a decimal point.

Since 2012 [`try_convert()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) is available. It'll convert when possible and otherwise return `NULL`.

```
SELECT try_convert(decimal(10, 2), pci1__c) pci1__c
       FROM mx_credit_analysis;
```